# Is there a Qt wrapper available for OpenAL

Tags: c++, qt, openal

To remove OpenAL dependency in Qt applications a Qt wrapper like QtOpenGL is required.

Comment: A wrapper doesn't remove the dependency, but makes the library easier to use, and allows it to integrate into other parts of the program. You still depend on OpenGL if you use QtOpenGL, and it's the same for OpenAL, wrapper or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any "official" wrappers for OpenAL for Qt, but you might want to look at this:

http://projects.developer.nokia.com/qt_openal_soft

As JamWaffles indicated, this won't remove your dependency on OpenAL; it merely wraps OpenAL to make integration into a Qt application somewhat easier.